# Abstract Algebra: Conjugates, Conjugacy Class, and Class Equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I have 3 questions that I would like step by step solutions to. But first, some context. The questions are from Charles Pinter's *A Book on Abstract Algebra*.

Let *G* be a finite group. Elements *a* and *b* in *G* are called *conjugates* of one another (in symbols, *a ~ b*) iff $a = xbx^{-1}$ for some *x* $\in$ *G* (this is the same as $b = x^{-1}ax$). The relation ~ is an equivalence relation in *G*; the equivalence class of any element *a* is called its *conjugacy class*. Hence *G* is partitioned into conjugacy classes; the size of each conjugacy class divides the order of *G*.

Let $S_1, S_2, ..., S_t$ be the distinct conjugacy classes of *G*, and let $k_1, k_2,..., k_t$ be their sizes. Then $|G| = k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_t$. (This is called *class equation* of *G*.)

Let *G* be a group whose order is a power of a prime *p*, say $|G| = p^k$. Let *C* denote the center of *G*.

The following 3 questions I have proved and I thought I should state them as my questions seem to build on from these:

1. The conjugacy class of *a* contains *a* (and no other element) iff *a* $\in$ *C*.
2. Let *c* be the order of *C*. Then $|G| = c + k_s + k_{s+1} + ... + k_t$ where $k_s, ..., k_t$ are the sizes of all the distinct conjugacy classes of elements *x* $\notin$ *C*.
3. For each $i  \in \{s, s+1, ...,t\}, k_i$ is equal to a power of *p*.

So, the 3 questions I need solutions to are the following:

4. Solving the equation $|G| = c + k_s + ... + k_t$ for c, explain why *c* is a multiple of *p*.
5. Prove: If $|G| = p^2$, *G* must be abelian.
6. Prove: If $|G| = p^2$, then either $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: For number 4, consider writing that equation modulo $p$. For number 5, think about your answers to 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5) You know that $|Z(G)| > 1$ so $|Z(G)| \in \{p, p^2\}$. If the order is $p^2$ then the center is the whole group hence abelian. If the order of the center is p then $G / Z(G)$ has order p and is cyclic. It is easy to prove that G/Z(G) cyclic then G is abelian.

6) We know that G is abelian and $\forall x \in G$, $|x| | p^2$ and only the identity has order 1. So if there exists an element of order $p^2$ then the group is cyclic. So pick an element in $ x \in G$ and note that the group generated by x is a proper subgroup with order p, pick any element not in that subgroup which will have order p.

Construct $\phi : (x) \times (y) \to G$ by $(u,v) \to uv$. This is a group homomorphism. The two subgroups have trivial intersection the map will be injective. Both groups have the same cardinality so the map will be an isomorphism.

Both (x),(y) are subgroups order p so they have a canonical isomorphism type namely $(x),(y) \simeq \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ so the result follows.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but after you picked x ∈ G to generate a proper subgroup, did you mean that you also picked y ∈ G such that x ≠ y and the order of y is also p?

Answer (score 0):

For $4$, recall that $|G|$ and all of $k_s,\ldots,k_t$ are multiples of $p$.

For $5$, note that the centre $C$ is nontrivial. What can be the structure of $C$ and of $G/C$?

For $6$, you can assume $G$ Abelian. What if it isn't cyclic? What can
you say about the order of its elements then?